# Develop asymptotic as $N \rightarrow \infty$ of $\sum_{k=1}^{\left\lfloor{N/2}\right\rfloor} \sum_{i=1}^{k} \sum_{d \mid i (2k-i), d > N} 1$

Tags: number-theory, summation, asymptotics, divisor-sum

This calculation arises from expansions of the number of factorable quadratics where the coefficients are constrained by naive height $N$.  In the above formula $d$ are the divisors of $i \left({2\, k - i}\right)$ subjected to the additional condition that $d > N$.  I do not expect that this sum is reducible.  If so that would also be welcomed.  My main result that I am looking for is the asymptotic expansion as $N \rightarrow \infty$ to all orders possible.  From other parts of this general calculation I have asymptotic terms of ${N}^{2} \log \left({N}\right)^{2}$ that this expansion should also have which will be canceled.  This is part of the reason why I need the other terms.

See [Asymptotic expansion as $N \rightarrow \infty$ of $\sum_{k=1}^{\left\lfloor{N/2}\right\rfloor} k \sum_{e \mid 2k}\frac{\Lambda \left({e}\right)}{e}$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3517870/asymptotic-expansion-as-n-rightarrow-infty-of-sum-k-1-left-lfloorn-2) for more details.

The maximum value of $i \left({2\, k - i}\right)$ is $\left\lfloor{N/2}\right\rfloor^{2}$ at $i = {k}_{max} = \left\lfloor{N/2}\right\rfloor$.

This can be reformulated.  The source of this problem is the calculation $${S}_{1} \left({N}\right) = \sum_{k=1}^{\left\lfloor{N/2}\right\rfloor} \sum_{i=1}^{k} \tau \left({i \left({2\, k - i}\right)}\right) - 2 \sum_{k=1}^{\left\lfloor{N/2}\right\rfloor} \sum_{i=1}^{k} \sum_{d \mid i \left({2\, k-i}\right), d > N}1$$ which comes from the problem of counting the number of reducible quadratics.  A slightly modified form which may be easier to expand asymptotically is $${S}_{1} \left({N}\right) = 2 \sum_{k=1}^{\left\lfloor{N/2}\right\rfloor} \sum_{i=1}^{k} \sum_{d \mid i \left({2\, k-i}\right), d \le N}1 - \sum_{k=1}^{\left\lfloor{N/2}\right\rfloor} \sum_{i=1}^{k} \tau \left({i \left({2\, k - i}\right)}\right)$$  I have some results for the asymptotic expansion of the $\tau \left({i \left({2\, k - i}\right)}\right)$ (which may or may not be correct since the reference that I am using assumes that for $\tau \left({n \left({n + v}\right)}\right)$ $v$ is a positive integer).  I have not be able to expand the first sum in ${S}_{1} \left({N}\right)$ which is a restatement of the posted problem.

Comment: I am counting the number of divisors of $i \left({2\, k - i}\right)$ that exceed $N$.  For the quadratic equation $r\, {x}^{2} + s\, x + t$ the coefficients are confined to $1 \le r \le N$ and $|s|, |t| \le N$.

Comment: I am counting the number of reducible quadratics with the above constraints on the coefficients.  What I am showing is just one part of the nine different sums.  Once I see how to do the above sum then I can complete four of them which are similar to the above statement.

Comment: I still don't see what you are trying to count. That $\exists i, d | i (2k-i)$ means that $x(2k-x)$ has a root $\bmod d$.

Comment: The full sum is $\sum_{k = 1}^{\left\lfloor{N/2}\right\rfloor} \sum_{i = 1}^{k} \tau \left({i \left({2\, k - i}\right)}\right) - 2 \sum_{k = 1}^{\left\lfloor{N/2}\right\rfloor} \sum_{d \mid i \left({2\, k - i}\right), d > N} 1$.  Where $\tau \left({x}\right)$ is the number of divisors.  I have been applying Adrian W. Dudek paper "Note on the number of divisors of reducible quadratic polynomials" on the first part.  There four such similar sums plus a final sum.  So the last sum (the above problem) is to count the divisors $d$ that are greater than $N$ of which I subtract for the correct count.

Comment: In the paper "Note on the number of divisors of reducible quadratic polynomials" the expansion is on $\sum_{n \le x} \tau \left({n \left({n + v}\right)}\right)$ where $v$ is a positive integer.  I am using this case with $v = - 2\, k$.  This avoids an zero argument of the number of divisors.  So it may still be valid.