# Asymptotic expansion as $N \rightarrow \infty$ of $\sum_{k=1}^{\left\lfloor{N/2}\right\rfloor} k \sum_{e \mid 2k}\frac{\Lambda \left({e}\right)}{e}$

Tags: elementary-number-theory, summation, asymptotics, divisor-sum

This expression comes from the asymptotic expansion of

$$\sum_{k=1}^{\left\lfloor{N/2}\right\rfloor} \sum_{i=1}^{k} \tau \left({i \left({2\, k - i}\right)}\right)$$

From Adrian W. Dudek, "Note on the number of divisors of reducible quadratic polynomials", arXiv:1806.01404v1 [math.NT] 4 Jun 2018.  Here $\tau \left({x}\right)$ us the number of divisors of $x$ and $\left\{{x}\right\}$ is the fractional part of $x$.

This expansion is $$\sum_{n \le x} \tau \left({n \left({n + v}\right)}\right) = \frac{6}{{\pi}^{2}} x \left({{\log}^{2} \left({x}\right) + {A}_{1} \left({v}\right) \log \left({x}\right) + {A}_{2} \left({v}\right)}\right) + O \left({{x}^{2/3 + \epsilon}}\right)$$
where $v$ is a positive integer (in this case I have $v = - 2\, k$ which may be valid as long as there is no $\tau \left({0}\right)$ case) and $${A}_{1} = 4\, \gamma- 2 - 4 \frac{{\zeta}^{\prime} \left({2}\right)}{\zeta \left({2}\right)} - 2\sum_{e \mid v} \frac{{\Lambda} \left({e}\right)}{e}$$ and $${A}_{2} = \left({2\, \gamma - 1 - 2 \frac{{\zeta}^{\prime} \left({2}\right)}{\zeta \left({2}\right)}}\right)^{2} + 1 - 4\frac{{\zeta}^{\prime \prime} \left({2}\right)}{\zeta \left({2}\right)} + 4 \left({\frac{{\zeta}^{\prime} \left({2}\right)}{\zeta \left({2}\right)}}\right)^{2} - \left({4\, \gamma- 2 - 4 \frac{{\zeta}^{\prime} \left({2}\right)}{\zeta \left({2}\right)}}\right) \sum_{e \mid v} \frac{{\Lambda} \left({e}\right)}{e} + 2 \sum_{e \mid v} \frac{{\Lambda} \left({e}\right) \log \left({e}\right)}{e} + \sum_{e \mid v} \frac{{\Lambda}_{2} \left({e}\right)}{e}$$ where ${\Lambda}_{k} \left({n}\right) = \sum_{d \mid n} \mu \left({d}\right) \left({\log \left({\frac{n}{d}}\right)}\right)^{k}$ which is the generalized Von Mangoldt function and $\Lambda \left({n}\right) = {\Lambda}_{1} \left({n}\right)$.

In general I am looking for the asymptotic expansions as $N \rightarrow \infty$ of $$\sum_{k=1}^{\left\lfloor{N/2}\right\rfloor} k \sum_{e \mid 2k} \frac{\Lambda \left({e}\right)}{e}$$ $$\sum_{k=1}^{\left\lfloor{N/2}\right\rfloor} k \log \left({k}\right) \sum_{e \mid 2k} \frac{\Lambda \left({e}\right)}{e}$$ $$\sum_{k=1}^{\left\lfloor{N/2}\right\rfloor} k \sum_{e \mid 2k} \frac{\Lambda \left({e}\right) \log \left({k}\right)}{e}$$ and $$\sum_{k=1}^{\left\lfloor{N/2}\right\rfloor} k \sum_{e \mid 2k} \frac{{\Lambda}_{2} \left({e}\right)}{e}$$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$$\sum_n (2n)^{-s} 2n \sum_{2d+1|2n} \frac{\Lambda(d)}d= (\frac{-\zeta'(s)}{\zeta(s)}-\frac{2^{-s}\log 2}{1-2^{-s}}) 2^{1-s}\zeta(s-1)$$
Following the same Tauberian theorem as in the proof of the PNT we get
$$\sum_{2n\le x}2n \sum_{2d+1|2n}\frac{\Lambda(d)}d\sim Res((\frac{-\zeta'(s)}{\zeta(s)}-\frac{2^{-s}\log 2}{1-2^{-s}}) 2^{1-s}\zeta(s-1)\frac{x^s}{s},2)$$ $$\sim \frac{x^2}{4}(\frac{-\zeta'(2)}{\zeta(2)}-\frac{2^{-2}\log 2}{1-2^{-2}})$$
The error term is $O(\frac{x^2}{\log^k x})$, under the RH it can be improved to $O(x^{3/2+\epsilon})$.

Comment: It is not clear as to how you arrived at the first answer.  Can you show more details.

Answer (score 0):

This is a partial answer for the case $$\sum_{k=1}^{\lfloor{N/2}\rfloor} k \sum_{e \mid 2k} \frac{\Lambda \left({e}\right)}{e}$$  See [Looking for a conversion of sum to a single sum over d where $\sum_{n = 1}^{x} n \sum_{d \mid 2n} \frac{\Lambda \left({d}\right)}{d}$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4748769/looking-for-a-conversion-of-sum-to-a-single-sum-over-d-where-sum-n-1x-n) for this solution.  This method will apply to the remaining 3 cases.